Telnetlib3 does not want to use UTF-8 encoding
I was trying to implement telnet server with telnetlib3 using Python. But everything works fine until I start using some UTF-8 encoding character, at that moment it breaks.
Here is my simple mock server to test this problem.
import asyncio
import telnetlib3

async def shell(reader, writer):
    writer.encoding = 'utf-8'
    writer.write('ดีคับ\n')
    writer.write('Type "exit" to close the connection.\n')
    
    while True:
        writer.write('> ')
        inp = await reader.read(1024)
        if not inp:
            break

        inp = inp.strip()
        if inp.lower() == 'exit':
            break

        writer.write(f'You said: {inp}\n')

    writer.write('Goodbye!\n')
    writer.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    server = telnetlib3.create_server(port=8023, shell=shell, host='0.0.0.0', encoding='utf-8')
    loop.run_until_complete(server)
    loop.run_forever()

I have tried to specify encoding in
server = telnetlib3.create_server(port=8023, shell=shell, host='0.0.0.0', encoding='utf-8'),
I tried both "utf-8" and "utf8".
But telnetlib3 still uses ASCII encoder to encode the string.
Here is the error (after I explicitly define a encoder utf-8).
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-4' coro=<shell() done, defined at /home/rinz/dev/test.py:4> exception=UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', 'ดีคับ\n', 0, 5, 'ordinal not in range(128)')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rinz/dev/test.py", line 6, in shell
    writer.write('ดีคับ\n')
  File "/home/rinz/dev/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/telnetlib3/stream_writer.py", line 2614, in write
    self._write(self.encode(string, errors))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rinz/dev/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/telnetlib3/stream_writer.py", line 2594, in encode
    return bytes(string, encoding, errors or self.encoding_errors)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)


What’s the client look like? Telnet defines a charset negotiation process which telnetlib3 implements; maybe the client has negotiated the ASCII encoding?

The default Windows telnet client for one does not support UTF-8. You may want to try a more capable one, like PuTTY. Running your code and connecting with PuTTY, I can see your text ดีคับ printed in the terminal. The code has other issues, but there are no encoding problems.

I use both putty and netcat (in linux terminal). Which is both of them can print the text without any problem
